# Ignore the writeOnly and sensitive fields in response OpenAPI bug

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Suppose my schema is (please ignore the syntax here, the syntax is correctly written in code) :

```
paymentAction:
  $ref: 'component/credit-card'
  $ref: 'component/google-pay'
discriminator:
  propertyName: paymentType
  mapping:
    cc: 'component/credit-card'
    gpay: 'component/google-pay'
```

The schema for them is as follows:

```
credit-card: 
 properties
  paymenytType:
   type: string
  paymentId:
   type: string
google-pay: 
 properties
  paymenytType:
   type: string
  paymentId:
   type: string
```

I want to exclude the paymentType from response sent to any request.

I've tried things like `x-field-extra-annotation: "package-path.JsonIgnore"`, keyword `writeOnly: true` and `x-class-extra-annotation: "package-path.JsonIgnoreProperties(value="paymentType")"`

But the paymentType is always sent in response even in get calls.
Using `openApi 3.0.3`, commands used `gradlew clean openApiGenerate`

`paymentAction` is generated as interface which is implemented by `credit-card` and `google-pay`

Please help!